# Word for an apprentice who outperforms their master?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

This has been puzzling me for years and my research so far hasn't turned up anything conclusive.

So is there a word which communicates the concept of **an apprentice outperforming their teacher**? I suspect the answer is most likely no—but if anyone knows differently and can tell me what that word is, that would be great.

Comment: Luke Skywalker? Darth Vader? [Take your pick.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SurpassedTheTeacher)

Comment: Could be prodigy? Although there's no aspect of betrayal

Comment: @newt, where's the aspect of betrayal in the question?

Comment: I wouldn't say betrayal, however the idea is very similar to Anakin overcoming Obi Wan in Star Wars.

Comment: *Showoff*? *Whippersnapper*? *Uppity little git*? 

Comment: @alwayslearning I suppose there isn't one, rereading the question, but the situation doesn't seem very positive? "outperforming" to me suggests an element of competition, or negative connotation, otherwise a word like "exceed" would be there

Comment: A student eventually 'graduates' but that doesn't speak to ability.  I don't think there is a word either.

Comment: "Upstart" comes to mind, but it has a negative connotation, and might apply even when the apprentice only *thinks* they're above the master.

Comment: @Qaz Quite so, just as we find in Goethe's "The Sorcerer's Apprentice".

Comment: @newt There doesn't need to be an element of competition, the teacher can feel pride and satisfaction in the achievements of the pupil. Not only that but without pupils who surpass their teachers we would have no progress; Amati taught Stadivarius how to work in wood and make violins and someone unknown taught Amati how to work in wood and to make musical instruments which weren't violins. Life goes on.

Answer (score 1):

#### If you're looking for an informal word, you can use '*bested*'.

[Which means](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/dictionary/bested):

> 13. to get the better of; defeat; beat

---

An example of it being used is:

> Until one day she *bested* her master...and left.

[image: XKCD 1337 Part 2]

Answer (score 0):

By definition wouldnt that be a savant. A person who has little or no training that is able to perform above expectations, above a normal person or trained person in a specific field.

Comment: I wouldn't use this word.